# bazel rules_nodejs can't resolve modules using custom package.json location

Tags: typescript, bazel, bazel-rules-nodejs

Bazel rules_nodejs can't resolve modules using custom package.json location.
Can someone help explain how to fix it?
Ideally I'd like to use a single `tsconfig.json` in `third_party/npm` instead.

```
bazel build //demo/node:bin
```

Gives error:

```
demo/node/src/lib.ts(1,19): error TS2307: Cannot find module 'chalk' or its corresponding type declarations.
```

Gist: https://gist.github.com/sbussard/9110d1bdcc784ca0a9303d4393e82f49

Folder structure

```
(repo root)
↳ WORKSPACE
↳ third_party
  ↳ npm
    ↳ package.json
    ↳ yarn.lock
↳ demo
  ↳ node
    ↳ BUILD
    ↳ tsconfig.json
    ↳ src
      ↳ lib.ts
```

`WORKSPACE`

```py
load("@bazel_tools//tools/build_defs/repo:http.bzl", "http_archive")
http_archive(
    name = "build_bazel_rules_nodejs",
    sha256 = "2b2004784358655f334925e7eadc7ba80f701144363df949b3293e1ae7a2fb7b",
    urls = ["https://github.com/bazelbuild/rules_nodejs/releases/download/5.4.0/rules_nodejs-5.4.0.tar.gz"],
)

load("@build_bazel_rules_nodejs//:repositories.bzl", "build_bazel_rules_nodejs_dependencies")

build_bazel_rules_nodejs_dependencies()

load("@build_bazel_rules_nodejs//:index.bzl", "node_repositories", "yarn_install")

node_repositories()

yarn_install(
    name = "npm",
    package_json = "//third_party/npm:package.json",
    yarn_lock = "//third_party/npm:yarn.lock",
)
```

`BUILD`

```py
load("@npm//@bazel/typescript:index.bzl", "ts_project")
load("@build_bazel_rules_nodejs//:index.bzl", "nodejs_binary")

ts_project(
    name = "lib",
    srcs = glob(["src/*.ts"]),
    deps = [
        "@npm//@types/chalk",
        "@npm//@types/node",
        "@npm//chalk",
    ],
)

nodejs_binary(
    name = "bin",
    data = [":lib"],
    entry_point = "src/lib.js",
)
```

`lib.ts`

```js
import chalk from 'chalk';

const { blue, red, green, yellow } = chalk;
const colors = [blue, red, yellow, blue, green, red];

console.log(
  'Google'
    .split('')
    .map((c, i) => colors[i % colors.length](c))
    .join('')
);
```

`package.json (inside dependencies)`

```
"@types/chalk": "^2.2.0",
"chalk": "^5.0.1",
```

`tsconfig.json`

```
{
  "include": ["src", "types"],
  "compilerOptions": {
    "module": "es2020",
    "target": "esnext",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "rootDir": "./",
    "paths": {
      "src/*": ["src/*"]
    },
    "strict": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "importsNotUsedAsValues": "error"
  }
}
```

Comment: Could you please provide more details on `package.json`?

Comment: It's just an "all in one" file to hold all dependencies for all projects. It hasn't been cleaned up at all at this point.

https://gist.github.com/sbussard/6d28031130c9fdeceda75edefc9c2e32

Comment: Thanks. Can you try add this line into your `package.json` as see does it works? `"type": "module",`

Comment: Yep. Doesn't work. Bazel is hard

Answer (score 1):

## TL;DR

### 1. `chalk` package

Run

`npm uninstall chalk`

and

`npm install chalk@"<5"`

to down grade the `chalk` package.

### 2. `BUILD` file

Remove this line `"@npm//@types/chalk",` under ts_project -> deps -> []

---

## 1. `chalk` package issue

I have faced the same issue with my Webpack setup.

This was a problem caused by TypeScript and `chalk`.

From [NPM: `chalk`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/chalk):

> IMPORTANT: Chalk 5 is ESM. If you want to use Chalk with TypeScript or
> a build tool, you will probably want to use Chalk 4 for now. Read
> more.

Following the above warning, we can find that

You are currently using:

> "chalk": "^5.0.1",

Please re-install and replace it:

```
"chalk": "<5",
```

And here is an example NPM script:

```
npm uninstall chalk

npm install chalk@"<5"
```

Currently, the latest version smaller than 5 is `v4.1.2`.

## 2. `BUILD` file

Hover on the [`TS icon`](https://static.npmjs.com/255a118f56f5346b97e56325a1217a16.svg) of the `chalk` package in [NPM: `chalk`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/chalk). It will show the following message:

> This package contains **built-in** TypeScript declarations

Which means it does not need `@type/chalk` package. And that's why it caused `BUILD file not found in directory '@types/chalk'` error.

So that, go to `BUILD` file and delete this line `"@npm//@types/chalk",` under ts_project -> deps -> []

### new `BUILD` file

```
load("@npm//@bazel/typescript:index.bzl", "ts_project")
load("@build_bazel_rules_nodejs//:index.bzl", "nodejs_binary")

ts_project(
    name = "lib",
    srcs = glob(["src/*.ts"]),
    deps = [
        "@npm//@types/node",
        "@npm//chalk",
    ],
)

nodejs_binary(
    name = "bin",
    data = [":lib"],
    entry_point = "src/lib.js",
)
```

After the above, you script will works fine.

Comment: Thanks you for your participation. Unfortunately it provides this error: `BUILD file not found in directory '@types/chalk'`

Comment: After reinstalling chalk and @types/chalk it gives this error `error TS2307: Cannot find module 'chalk' or its corresponding type declarations.`

Comment: I have updated the answer. Thank you for your further information. Feel free to let me know when you have any more issue. ;)

Comment: It still fails with the same error. I think it might be a tsconfig issue. Ideally there would be one tsconfig file for the whole repo, ideally in the third_party/npm folder. Thanks for continuing to look into this!

Comment: I just trying to share my experience. IC, I also came up with this when I setting up the `webpack` with `typescript`. Try to change `"module": "CommonJS",`. I guess it could help and if so I will update my answer.

Comment: A little more thing, if `"module": "CommonJS",` still does not work. Would you mind to share your setup or a [`reprex`](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) on something like github please? That would be easier for debugging.

Comment: IIRC Bazel doesn't have an online equivalent to codesandbox.io, so this is the best I can do
https://gist.github.com/sbussard/9110d1bdcc784ca0a9303d4393e82f49

Answer (score 1):

According to [Chalk](https://www.npmjs.com/package/chalk#install):

> IMPORTANT: Chalk 5 is ESM. If you want to use Chalk with TypeScript or a build tool, you will probably want to use Chalk 4 for now. [Read more.](https://github.com/chalk/chalk/releases/tag/v5.0.0)

There are a few fixes for this issue.

---

**1. Use Chalk 4 (recommended for TypeScript)**

The first solution is to use Chalk 4. You will not be missing out on many features by downgrading to Chalk 4.

To do this, you need to first change your versions in `package.json`. Change them to this.

```json
{
  "dependencies": {
    "chalk": "4.1.2"
  }
}
```

*Note: TypeScript types (`@types/chalk`) aren't required, as Chalk has built-in TypeScript declarations.*

After that, you can delete the `node_modules` folder to remove all of the packages.

Then, we can run the installation command again to reinstall `chalk`, as well as the other packages that you have.

```
$ npm install
```

Then, as Chalk 4 doesn't use `import`, you need to change your `import` to use `require()`.

```js
const chalk = require("chalk");
```

This should correctly install Chalk 4.

---

**2. Change `type` to `module`**

The second solution is to change the `type` to `module` in `package.json`. This will allow ESM imports in your files.

```json
{
  "type": "module"
}
```

You do not need to change anything else in your files. However, you can't use CommonJS imports (e.g. `require()`) with this set.

---

**3. Use the `import()` function**

Another solution is to use the `import()` function, without adding the `type: module` in the `package.json` file.

To do this, you first need to make sure that this line of code **isn't** in your `package.json` file.

```json
{
  "type": "module"
}
```

Then, you need to change the `import` statement for `chalk` to the following.

```js
const chalk = await import("chalk");
```

This function allows both the CommonJS module setting set, as well as an ESM-like `import` statement. You just need to make sure that you are using the LTS version of Node.js, which supports top-level `await`.

---

In conclusion, these solutions should help solve your issue. However, the first solution is recommended for TypeScript.

Comment: Thanks for your contribution to the conversation. Unfortunately bazel and typescript seem to have some difficulties working together, which I believe is at the heart of the issue

Comment: Oh, okay. I'll see if I can find another solution. Have you tried my solution yet?

Comment: Yeah, it didn't work

Comment: Oh, okay. I haven't found any solutions yet.

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same kind of error when `package.json` wasn't at the root of the folder.

Setting [`package_path = "/"`](https://bazelbuild.github.io/rules_nodejs/Built-ins.html#npm_install-package_path) in `yarn_install` fixed the problem.